# How do I set up the .wsgi file and apache configuration to deploy on a Large Flask Application on a Debain Server?

Tags: flask, debian, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have created a Flask Application based on the [Large Application Structure](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky) in Miguel Grinberg's Flask Web Development Book. I have followed the tutorial in [how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and have managed to deploy a single file Flask application on my server. What changes/ modifications do I have to implement to my .wsgi file and apache config to be able to host Large Structured applications?

My Apache2 .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName devrupt.com
        ServerAdmin lui@devrupt.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Devrupt/devrupt.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/static
        <Directory /var/www/Devrupt/Devrupt/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My .wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/Devrupt/")

from Devrupt import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/rootdir
WSGIDaemonProcess <projectname> user=flask group=www-data threads=2 home=/path/to/rootdir/project
WSGIProcessGroup <projectname>
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/rootdir/project/flask.wsgi
```

And if You're using virtualenv add this to .wsgi file:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/rootdir/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: I have added the .wsgi file in the question.

Comment: nope, still unable to display my Flask application. 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/ 
states that "If you don’t have a factory function for application creation but a singleton instance you can directly import that one as application." 
How do i import it for an app with factory function for application creation?

Comment: The Large Application Structure example uses a factory function.

Comment: @dirn How do i create a .wsgi file for a factory function?

Comment: You import the function, call it, and assign its return value to `application`.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this